# How to filter a value in json field type on Postgres 9.2?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

My json field data is like this:

```
{"active":true,"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","settings":{"secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","expires":"2019-12-16 01:11:23"},"plan":"Sample"}
```

Then I tried to query the field like this:

```
select * from integrations.accounts where field -> 'id' = 'xxxxxx';
```

But it gives me an error of:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: json -> unknown

I found that the arrow operator (->) is not supported in version 9.2:

Unsupported versions: 9.3 / 9.2

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no true support for JSON in your version (It is really recommended to upgrade!) you have to parse your JSON text manually in any way. For example with help of regexp:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=73ebb148682b695abfc77c375d1618f6)

```
SELECT 
    (regexp_matches(my_json_value::text, '"id":"(.*?)"'))[1]
```

Comment: @Juan Did this answer help you? If not, how can I help? If so, please do not forget to accept (close) and upvote the helpful answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

`->` is used for traversing the nested JSON

`->>` is used for the selection of querying level

In the above example if you wanna query on `token` which is inside `settings` you can use the following command

```
select * from integrations.accounts where field -> 'settings' ->> 'token' = 'xxxxxx';
```

To query on id which is at the top level use the following command

```
select * from integrations.accounts where field ->> 'id' = 'xxxxxx';
```